# C# Attempted to read or write protected memory

Tags: asp.net, .net, winforms, c#-4.0

I received the following error `"Attempted to read or write protected memory"` on `richTextBox_Console.AppendText`

```
public void ConsoleWriteLine(string formatedText, bool urgent = false)
{
    try
    {
        if (richTextBox_Console.InvokeRequired)
        {
            richTextBox_Console.BeginInvoke(new ConsoleWriteDelegate(ConsoleWriteLine), formatedText, urgent);
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            if (!tabPage_Console.Focused && urgent)
                tabPage_Console.Text = "Console(!)";
            richTextBox_Console.AppendText(formatedText + Environment.NewLine);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception Exc)
    {
        Testing.ExceptionHandler.HandleException(Exc);
    }
}

public static MainForm View;
[STAThread]
static void Main()
{
    FlatfileDB.Load();
    LoadDatabase();

    Application.EnableVisualStyles();
    Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);

    View = new MainForm();
    Application.Run(View);
}

public static void HandleException(string Exc)
{
    try
    {
        using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter("Exceptions.txt", true))
        {
            writer.WriteLine(string.Format("[{0}] \r\n{1}\r\n", DateTime.Now.ToString(), Exc.ToString()));
            writer.Flush();
        }
        Program.View.ConsoleWriteLine("Exception has been handled. See Exceptions.txt", true);
    }
    catch { }
}
```

any explanation as to why this could have occurred would be wonderful.

- Please note this error didn't occur instantly it happened over the course of a few hours.
- I'm using net 4.5

Comment: Can you show the implementation of this `AppendText` method?

Comment: @PMF: It's a .NET framework class and method.

Comment: That's correct... I've updated my post with a sample of how It's being used.

Comment: Does the code work if you continue after the exception? In other words, does it get caught in `Testing.ExceptionHandler.HandleException(Exc);` or not, and is it only shown by Visual Studio while debuggin?

Comment: You might also seek the problem in `string formatedText` being a reference type, being corrupted somewhere. I doubt the problem has to do anything with `richTextBox_Console.AppendText`. Maybe you can try to validate you have access to `string formatedText` before using it in `richTextBox_Console.AppendText` to see if it is a problem of the string or the `AppendText`.

Comment: This question appears to be attracting attention, but the OP account is deleted. Questions to the OP will never get a response and this question will never have an accepted answer.  Better that other similar questions get the attention.